# Font substitution in Ghostscript

Tags: fonts, ghostscript

Does anyone know if there is a way to do a global font substitution in Ghostscript?

I can identify and substitute fonts on an individual basis using the font map but I would like to have it replace everything automatically if not found.

I am using Ghostscript in an automated environment and would prefer to have the output be incorrect/ugly until the font substitution can be determined rather than error result.

Answer (score 2):

For font substitution details, please lookup the [`-sSUBSTFONT=fontname` parameter for Ghostscript in their official documentation (in Use.htm)](https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/Use.htm#FONTMAP_switch).

However, Ghostscript already uses a font substitution automatism by default which has a certain level of intelligence built in (or do you, maybe inadvertedly, override that with your own commandline?), so the above may only be the second best option...

Comment: `-SSUBSTFONT` only substitutes unknown fonts. Is there a way to substitute known fonts?

Comment: @Geremia: This can be done for CID fonts and it is documented here: https://www.ghostscript.com/doc/Use.htm#CIDFontSubstitution

Comment: BTW, you can use, for example, `-sSUBSTFONT=Courier` as well as `-dSUBSTFONT=/Courier`.

Comment: What's the difference between `-s` and `-d`?

Comment: Can please you give a specific example of CID font substitution? thanks

Comment: @Geremia: Please don't abuse comments to ask new questions.

Comment: Ghostscript handles `-s...` values as a (freetext) string. It handles `-d...` values as (PostScript) tokens (which are pre-defined).

Comment: I've opened a new question: "[-sSUBSTFONT, -sCIDFSubstFont, -sCIDFSubstPath not substituting PDF fonts](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67494788/1429450)"