# -sSUBSTFONT, -sCIDFSubstFont, -sCIDFSubstPath not substituting PDF fonts

Tags: fonts, ghostscript, substitution

`in.pdf` has these fonts:

```
name                                 type              encoding         emb sub uni object ID
------------------------------------ ----------------- ---------------- --- --- --- ---------
XUBADJ+GlyphLessFont                 CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    236  0
JZXXTO+GlyphLessFont                 CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    232  0
NXIYZI+GlyphLessFont                 CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    228  0
PQVSVF+GlyphLessFont                 CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    224  0
TCZVSD+GlyphLessFont                 CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    220  0
XQFVGO+GlyphLessFont                 CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    216  0
RBABWN+GlyphLessFont                 CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    212  0
VZZOSB+GlyphLessFont                 CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    209  0
MIIWJT+GlyphLessFont                 CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    204  0
POGIAG+GlyphLessFont                 CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    200  0
XCWYMK+GlyphLessFont                 CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    196  0
DYONOM+GlyphLessFont                 CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    192  0
UAXGNC+GlyphLessFont                 CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    188  0
SFJKWI+GlyphLessFont                 CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    184  0
FNZBKK+GlyphLessFont                 CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    180  0
HAZYJU+GlyphLessFont                 CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    176  0
ZVQPUS+GlyphLessFont                 CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    172  0
PQZKFS+GlyphLessFont                 CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    168  0
PGOAHQ+GlyphLessFont                 CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    164  0
XDOPUZ+GlyphLessFont                 CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    160  0
RFWRSV+GlyphLessFont                 CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    156  0
IANVPF+GlyphLessFont                 CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    152  0
DSZVBD+GlyphLessFont                 CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    148  0
LSDXRT+GlyphLessFont                 CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    144  0
XIHSWO+GlyphLessFont                 CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    141  0
TEWAEV+GlyphLessFont                 CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    136  0
LYKOSV+GlyphLessFont                 CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    132  0
BNAIKQ+GlyphLessFont                 CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    128  0
ZNALBH+GlyphLessFont                 CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    124  0
FFPURC+GlyphLessFont                 CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    120  0
TAEOHD+GlyphLessFont                 CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    116  0
RLNSOX+GlyphLessFont                 CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    113  0
LKNUZY+GlyphLessFont                 CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    108  0
RDFYMU+GlyphLessFont                 CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    104  0
NXOHWC+GlyphLessFont                 CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes    100  0
LUDJFV+GlyphLessFont                 CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes     96  0
RRUFPY+GlyphLessFont                 CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes     92  0
CDUACC+GlyphLessFont                 CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes     88  0
RNMQSS+GlyphLessFont                 CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes     85  0
PDSWJI+GlyphLessFont                 CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes     80  0
BHBSVQ+GlyphLessFont                 CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes     76  0
NNFGOY+GlyphLessFont                 CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes     72  0
LSTBQQ+GlyphLessFont                 CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes     68  0
XOTJDO+GlyphLessFont                 CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes     64  0
DQQCUP+GlyphLessFont                 CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes     61  0
DSVQZE+GlyphLessFont                 CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes     57  0
VSPFUZ+GlyphLessFont                 CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes     52  0
FVVDEA+GlyphLessFont                 CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes     48  0
NZFHZN+GlyphLessFont                 CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes     45  0
NJXGBN+GlyphLessFont                 CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes     41  0
DWTFYL+GlyphLessFont                 CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes     37  0
PKYUOD+GlyphLessFont                 CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes     33  0
LGBPPA+GlyphLessFont                 CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes     29  0
ROGTHG+GlyphLessFont                 CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes     25  0
ZBKUCS+GlyphLessFont                 CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes     20  0
ZBOPFI+GlyphLessFont                 CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes     17  0
RZCJNG+GlyphLessFont                 CID TrueType      Identity-H       yes yes yes     13  0
```

Why doesn't running this

```
gs -q -o out.pdf -sDEVICE=pdfwrite -sCIDFSubstPath=/usr/share/fonts/TTF/ -sCIDFSubstFont=LiberationSans-Regular.ttf -sSUBSTFONT=LiberationSans-Regular in.pdf
```

produce an `out.pdf` with LiberationSans-Regular fonts? Instead, `pdffonts out.pdf` gives the same output as it did for `in.pdf` above.

Comment: Nice table! How do typically extract a list of fonts from PDF to produce such table?

Answer (score 1):

The CIDFont substitution parameters influence substituting *missing* CIDFonts. You can't replace embedded CIDFonts - and all the ones listed in your file are embedded. Simply dropping in a different font/CIDFont isn't really possible, in the general case.